# Typescript changing type structure depending on object value

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union, type-narrowing

I have a API that returns a big array of data that's a mixture of objects where the data structure changes depending on the type and I cannot understand how I should create a good type structure for it.
I believed I had done it right but when I try to check for which type it is I get the error Property X does not exist on type.

```
type EchoGroup = {
  group: {
    img: { name: string; type: "ECHO" };
    specialData: { meta: string; copy: string }[];
  };
  owner: boolean;
};
type CharlieGroup = {
  group: {
    img: { name: string; type: "CHARLIE" };
    specialData: { meta: string; usage: string; price: number }[];
  };
  owner: boolean;
};

const sample: (EchoGroup | CharlieGroup)[] = [
  {
    group: {
      img: { name: "Test 1", type: "CHARLIE" },
      specialData: [
        { meta: "string", usage: "private", price: 10 },
        { meta: "string", usage: "public", price: 20 },
      ],
    },
    owner: false,
  },
  {
    group: {
      img: { name: "Test 2", type: "ECHO" },
      specialData: [{ meta: "string", copy: "private" }],
    },
    owner: true,
  },
];
sample.map((single: EchoGroup | CharlieGroup) => {
  switch (single.group.img.type) {
    case "ECHO":
      console.log(single.group.specialData[0].copy);
      // Error:
      // Property 'copy' does not exist on type '{ meta: string; copy: string; }[] | { meta: string; usage: string; price: number; }[]'.
      // Property 'copy' does not exist on type '{ meta: string; copy: string; }[]'.
      break;
    case "CHARLIE":
      console.log(single.group.specialData[0].price);
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: Maybe your data is not OK, as you are checking for  type `ECHO` and still there is no `copy` property.

Comment: A simple solution is change `single: EchoGroup | CharlieGroup` to `single: any` but you lost the typed object structure validation

Comment: I cannot see any problem in the data and it should be correctly typed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is typescript's type narrowing [doesn't narrow type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758) of the parent objects depending on child's discriminant values:

```ts
type A = { type: "a", a: number }
type B = { type: "b", b: number }

type X = { type: A, a: string }
type Y = { type: B, b: string }

declare let x: X | Y

if (x.type.type === "a") {
    x.a // Type Error
    x.type.a // no error. `x.type` is narrowed to A
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Nalopw)

> A discriminant property only applies to the object it's directly a member of. So in your example, inside the if block, you can access x.type.a (but not x.type.b), but there are no effects on the containing object x.

There is a [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/38839) to provide this kind of functionality. But it's still work in progress.

As of now the only way to narrow type inside any structure is to keep the discriminant property on the same or upper level:

```ts
type EchoGroup = {
  group: {
    type: 'ECHO',
    img: { name: string };
    specialData: { meta: string; copy: string }[];
  };
  owner: boolean;
};
type CharlieGroup = {
  group: {
    type: 'CHARLIE',
    img: { name: string };
    specialData: { meta: string; usage: string; price: number }[];
  };
  owner: boolean;
};
...
sample.map((single: EchoGroup | CharlieGroup) => {
  switch (single.group.type) {
    case "ECHO":
      console.log(single.group.specialData[0].copy); // works as expected
      break;
    case "CHARLIE":
      console.log(single.group.specialData[0].price); // works too
      break;
  }
});
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mxo4zN)